# Starting problem with persistent(casper-rw) file in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have recently downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 amd 64 bit version to try on my (Sony Vaio Intel® Core™ i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4, RAM 4GB) system. Then I have created a live boot-able usb(8GB) with help of first Unetbootin & then YUMI. While creating the live usb I have chosen 3072MB as size of the persistent file(casper-rw).

On first run it booted and the take me to the live user session. But when I tried to start Firefox it had crashed - so I have to end that session there.

Now when-ever I have tried to start a live session with the persistent file system active it fails to start, but if I remove the persistent file system entry checking by the boot loader it works fine and the 'live user session' could be started.

I need the 'persistent file' for saving internet downloading history so that I can resume download of unfinished files.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

### Persistent live systems are very portable between computers

- Persistent live systems are very portable, which is a good reason to use them.

### Persistent live systems are sensitive to corruption

- if the system crashes (which happened to you)
- if you unplug the pendrive without unmounting the mounted partition(s) which means that you must shut down gracefully and let the shutdown process finish
- if you install too many program packages or update & upgrade completely.

I suggest that you try a persistent live system made with mkusb. See the following links,

- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

You should backup your system often.

- While it is healthy, you can backup (and restore) the whole `casper-rw` partition.

  - [Backup and restore of persistent overlay data](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data)
- Otherwise you can be saved by backing up your `/home` directory in the  `casper-rw` partition. Create a fresh persistent live drive with mkusb and restore `/home` according to the following links,

  - [Backup and restore the /home directory in casper-rw partitions of mkusb persistent drives](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259682&p=13768700#post13768700)
  - [How do I upgrade a mkusb Persistent Live system from 16.04 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039898/how-do-i-upgrade-a-mkusb-persistent-live-system-from-16-04-to-18-04/1039967#1039967)

### Installed systems in external drives are portable and stable

Installed systems in external drives are portable,

- but not as portable as persistent live systems
- you can install program packages and update & upgrade completely like any installed system (as long as there is drive space for it)
- but if you unplug the pendrive before shutting down gracefully and let the shutdown process finish, this file system will probably be corrupted too.

This might be an alternative for you, if portable enough. See this link,

- [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

### Repair the `ext` file system in `casper-rw`

If the file system in the `casper-rw` partition or file is not too corrupted, you can get a working USB pendrive again after repairing the file system.

- Boot from another linux system
- check that `casper-rw` is not mounted
- Run the following repair command

  ```
  sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdxn
  ```

  where x is the device letter and n is the partition number, so typically for a persistent live drive by mkusb

  ```
  sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdb5
  ```

  See this link for more details,

  - [Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)
- If you stay with a `casper-rw` *file*, you can try the following command

  ```
  sudo e2fsck -f mountpoint-of-FAT-partition/casper-rw
  ```

  Example:

  ```
  $ sudo e2fsck -f /mnt/sd1/casper-rw
  e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
  Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
  Pass 2: Checking directory structure
  Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
  Pass 4: Checking reference counts
  Pass 5: Checking group summary information
  /mnt/sd1/casper-rw: 11/262144 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 18510/1048320 blocks
  ```